# Fastest non-server side redirect method

Tags: redirect, refresh

I am trying to redirect users to a page, only from a specific page.

I have tried meta Refresh, windows.location, top.location.replace, but they all take a little too long to redirect as my client needs the page changed instantly or as close as possible. I am wondering if there is a faster, non-server method to do so. php header is also not an option as the script has to be placed within a page.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Soo... What's the fastest server side redirect, with php? I want to detect what browser someone has (between FF chrome and safari) and redirect accordingly for a browser extension. Basically the page has not purpose other than to rout you according to your browser, and would have not html on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place both the meta and javascript method of your choice as close to the top as possible. Those are ALL the client-side redirect methods.

You can't get any faster without speeding up your server, or cutting down on page load time. If you can make the page load faster by removing content and/or images, external files, etc., you can improve the performance slightly.

If you really want to get into silly extremes, if you can pre-load the target page in a prior page in a hidden iframe, the transition will seem close to instant as the browser hits the local cache and skips the DNS lookup. Make sure your etags and cache control headers are set properly server side.

If you're concerned about the flicker where the client sees a real page load before getting redirected, consider setting the content to hidden with an inline style, or covering it with a white div, or something similar.

Comment: Quibble: Meta refresh may behave differently than the two script based command based on browser.

Comment: Fair point. Best to include both methods, to get as many browsers as possible, but you may slow down page load time a tiny smidgen by doing so. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I will try experimenting with hiding the original page but the redirect is loaded within an if clause, else the regular page is displayed, thus I would have to hide the entire page's content only within the if which is IN the page..

Comment: If you hide it by default and then remove the hiding conditionally using javascript, you'll slow down your regular page load times slightly but avoid the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that a meta-refresh would be the faster of those mentioned. Simply for the fact that it is top on the document and that JavaScript `<script>` tags are blocking while interpreted.

Comment: True, but it doesn't work reliably across all browsers. If the browser accepts the meta, it will start working on it immediately after the page loads. If not, the javascript will start working at that point.